# MediaWiki: number of pages on Special:AllPages

Tags: mediawiki

Is there any settings to change maximum count limit of pages before MediaWiki group them into names ranges on Special:AllPages?

Something like that but "from A to Z all on one page, without need of choose alphabetical range".
http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Special:AllPages

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `includes/specials/SpecialAllPages.php`, you'll see the following code at the top of the file:

```
/**
 * Maximum number of pages to show on single subpage.
 */
protected $maxPerPage = 345;
```

Change that number to whatever you want to be the limit.

Comment: As of 2022 in latest version of mediawiki there is still this magic number there, with no documentation, no comment, no explanation... They could at least have made it into a global variable ($wg..) in LocalSettings...

Answer (score -2):

No, it's impossible. You can try [wikiteams's dumpgenerator](https://code.google.com/p/wikiteam/) or pywikipediabot's pagegenerators.

Comment: Thanks for help, after trying make this working, I ended with MediaWiki API. Exported to JSON and made PHP script exactly how I wished. It was wiki with about 500 pages, so it wasn't big deal.